# Barty Crouch Jr uttering Lord Voldemort's name?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Barty Crouch Jr (as an imposter of MadEye Moody) utters Lord Voldemort's name soon after Harry returns to Hogwarts from the graveyard. He asks Harry if Voldemort has really returned and whether Voldemort punished the Death Eaters, and so on. As far as I know Death Eaters never spoke Lord Voldemort's name. This seems inconsistent. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Why wouldn't they speak his name? The main (only?) reason for referring to Voldemort as You-Know-Who or He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named is fear, and his followers would have less reason to fear him.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist..perhaps if you go through the books thoroughly,you will find that there is not a single instance(except of course the above quoted one) in the series,where in the Death-Eaters take the name of Lord Voldemort.Also,I suppose his followers will have more reason to fear him..more that non-Death-Eaters,as they are the first ones to suffer his anguish in situations of betrayal ..

Comment: Crouch calling him by name is certainly unusual, Death Eaters usually address their leader as The Dark Lord.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mainly, Barty Crouch Jr thought himself to be Voldemort's most faithful Death Eater; it's possible he anointed himself as being worthy of speaking Voldemort's name and as having earned the right to do so.

> ‘Tell me he told them that I, I alone remained faithful ... prepared to risk everything to deliver to him the one thing he wanted above all ... [Harry Potter].’
>   <sub>*Goblet of Fire*  - page 587 - Bloomsbury - chapter 35, *Veritaserum*</sub>

I personally don't interpret the Polyjuice Potion as being relevant; after saying Voldemort's name in front of Harry, Crouch Jr went on to give a full confession of his plan and actions over the past nine months, and then he attempted to kill Harry, all while still Polyjuiced. I don't think he was concerned about saying Voldemort's name in front of Harry because his intention was to kill Harry; there would be no witness to Crouch Jr saying Voldemort's name if Harry were dead.

Answer (score 2):

Barty obviously didn't want to make Harry suspicious before his polyjuice potion wore off.

Comment: I don't think he would have made Harry suspicious though..Harry might have just thought he is one among many  people who addressed Voldemort as You-Know-Who..